# Enable or disable VS Code Integrated Terminal Tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to get tabs instead of the select list when using multiple terminals from the "integrated terminal" window?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Terminal "tabs" appear to be coming to v1.56. See [Terminal Tabs release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_56.md#terminal-tabs).  They are vertical tabs - always visible, if you want, in a resizable view to the left or right.  Not like traditional tabs across the top like a browser though.

> Tabs in the terminal [are] available as a preview feature and can be
> enabled with the following setting:

```json
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
```

> The tabs view is a split pane to the right of two split terminals. It
> contains icons and labels for each terminal instance.
>
> When enabled, the new tabs view will only show by default when there
> is at least 2 terminals.

---

> We've tried to mostly align how the new tabs behave with how the
> explorer works, here are some of the other behaviors:
>
> - Double clicking the empty space will create a new terminal.
> - Double clicking the sash will toggle the tabs view width between the "ideal" size which displays all the titles without truncating and a
>   narrow view that shows only the icons.
> - The tabs can be moved to the left side using the `terminal.integrated.tabs.location` setting.
> - Various other configuration settings available under `terminal.integrated.tabs`.

---

> #### Terminal Statuses
>
> Along with tabs, we have introduced the concept of statuses to the
> terminal. A terminal can have many statuses, each of which represents
> a state the terminal can be in temporarily, with the highest severity
> one being displayed next to the tab. Status icons appear to the right
> of the terminal title in the tabs view. On hover, details of the
> status and any associated actions are presented.
>
> On a tab associated with a terminal that requires a relaunch, a
> yellow triangle with an exclamation mark is to the right of the
> terminal title.
>
> For now, these states are supported:
>
> - Relaunch needed: A warning icon status is used if extensions want to change a terminal's environment.
> - Disconnected: A plug icon status is used when the terminal loses its connection with its process.
> - Bell: A bell icon appears when the bell is enabled via the `terminal.integrated.enableBell` setting and the terminal bell
>   triggers.
>
> We plan to support task states soon so that task run status is
> available at a glance even without activating the tab.

And more at the link.  From the Insiders Build:

[image: Terminal Tabs demo]

Answer (score 4):

**NO EXTENSION REQUIRED**, as [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-splitting) say:

```
Ctrl+Shift+5
```

If enough space, you can press it multiple times. However, as always, extensions might be more sophisticated for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Requested by the community in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10546

Added in release 1.57 (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases)

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Terminal Tabs" and you can un-check them to turn them off. Go to your VS code setting `User->Features->Terminal` and look for the section called "Integrated > Tabs:Enabled" and un-check it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that does this by adding tabs to the status bar: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.terminal-tabs

Comment: Oh, you should file an issue on https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-terminal-tabs. Not sure what would be os-specific about this