# How to set drop down view in integrated terminal on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Initially VS Code showed a drop down list for all the terminals available but now it is just showing plus sign and new terminals get added to right pane.
How do I enable like this: (plus sign and the drop down view)

[image]

In my current VS Code it got changed to:

[image]

I don't know if its due to update or I messed up some settings.

Comment: Is this setting `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled"` set to `false`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309079/836330

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. (on a mac) go to code > preferences > Settings. You'll need to find the setting under terminal or just search 'terminal' in the search bar. you'll be looking for the following setting and just make sure it is unchecked. [image]

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to fiddle with the settings, a quick fix is to open 2 terminals, then right-click on the space below the list of terminals, and click "hide tabs".

Comment: This answer works best for me. I didn't initiate tabs via settings; I did it by clicking the "show tabs" link at the bottom of the dropdown. I would never think to go to settings to switch it back.