# My vs code is not showing drop down option to select terminal from a list of terminal. How to change it to normal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Instead, it is showing side pane with list of open terminals. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z6z6.png)

Comment: See the setting here to check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309079/836330

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on the down arrow besides the + icon in the terminal
2. Select terminal settings. it would open the settings.
3. Search for Terminal → Integrated → Tabs: Enabled
4. De-select the option . it would display the open terminals in a drop down menu.

See image for the setting:

[image]