# How do I bring back the drop-down menu on the terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to switch between terminals and accidentally changed the icon. Now instead of the drop down menu I have this:

[image: Terminal menu]

I've looked around the setting to see if I can change it back, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: try clicking the downward facing arrow in the screenshot, or maybe the icon itself?

Comment: Disable the `Terminal Tabs` option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406096/enable-or-disable-vs-code-integrated-terminal-tabs/67309079?r=SearchResults&s=1|89.3448#67309079