# How do i toggle open vscode terminal right sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The one on the right in the screenshot below. It's also useful to know what is it called

[image]

Comment: Those are the terminal tabs - which can be disabled, so you go back to the old dropdown list instead.  With 3 terminal tabs open I don't know how you can toggle it off.  I would have thought that the setting terminal tabs `Hide Condition` : `singleGroup` would do it (assuming that means no splits).  But that setting makes no difference for me.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406096/enable-or-disable-vs-code-integrated-terminal-tabs/67309079?r=SearchResults&s=1|89.5850#67309079 to disable tabs in favor of the old dropdown list.

Comment: i saw this in a video, i want to view it not close it

Comment: First, what version of vscode are you running?  That is only available in v1.57.  And only if you have multiple terminals open.