# How to change vscode terminal to deafult drop-down style

Tags: visual-studio-code

All of a sudden something I did and the terminal changed its ui and it was looking like below
[image]

I don't like this style. Split terminal list appearing on right side looks akward. I want it to be the old terminal like below with drop-down

[image]

Please anyone help me

Comment: have you searched SO for this question, id is answered multiple times, look in the date range of when it was introduced, or look in the release notes of VSC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable or disable VS Code Integrated Terminal Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406096/enable-or-disable-vs-code-integrated-terminal-tabs)  You can also right click in the tabs section and select "Hide Tabs" to revert the setting.

Comment: @TimothyG. That doesn't answer my question friend. If the link you sent returns my old tab back please provide the steps here. If i feel this question doesn't make any sense i'll delete it. but with all information from this comment section still I'm unable to return to that old tab. I'm not getting what to do !

Comment: @rioV8 please share the answer link if you have seen answer somewhere. I'm a dumb person couldn't able to search answer for this from past 3 days. vscode docs are very good but as expected I couldn't able to find!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it,

**settings -> User -> Features -> Terminal -> Integrated>Tabs:Enabled**
`select/deselect` to change the terminal

[image]