# how to change new version of the terminal to the old version?

Tags: vscode-tasks

My vscode get an update, and after that my terminal get other design so I would like to come back to the old.

My terminal was like this:

[image: good terminal]

And now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable or disable VS Code Integrated Terminal Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406096/enable-or-disable-vs-code-integrated-terminal-tabs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to press `ctrl+shif+p` and then write `Open settings(JSON)`

And there you have to add next line:

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false
```

In case the line there is yet, you just have to turn it `false`